# React, ES6 compiling with Browserify, babel and gulp, issue importing components

Tags: reactjs, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I'm playing with ES6, Gulp and Browserify, I'm on my first steps setting up my environment.

**This is my [browserify task](https://gist.github.com/nramirez/5611abb6f1dd15ab0432#file-gulpfile-babel-js):**

```
gulp.task('client', cb => {
return browserify({
        entries: paths.publicEntries, 
        extensions: ['.jsx'], 
        debug: true
    })
    .transform('babelify', {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source(paths.bundle))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.bundleDest));
});
```

**This is may main script [index.jsx](https://gist.github.com/nramirez/5611abb6f1dd15ab0432#file-index-jsx)**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TestPage from './components/test';

(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <TestPage/>,
    document.getElementById('mainContainer')
  );
})();
```

**This is a component I created [test.jsx](https://gist.github.com/nramirez/5611abb6f1dd15ab0432#file-test-jsx)**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

class TestPage extends React.Component {
  render()
  {
    return <h1> Hello World! </h1>
  }
}

export default TestPage;
```

Everything looks right to me, but there's a weird behavior using the import statements in the `index.jsx` (I don't exactly know where the problem is).

**To be sure what is working and what is not, I replaced the import of my component for the actual code as follows:**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import TestPage from './components/test';

class TestPage extends React.Component {
  render()
  {
    return <h1> Hello World! </h1>
  }
}

(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <TestPage/>,
    document.getElementById('mainContainer')
  );
})();
```

[image]

**Here everything is working right, but if I use the standard `import` statement I get nothing:**

[image]

**Notice:**

- `./component/test.jsx` and `./index.jsx` are loaded correctly.
- I don't have any error when I'm running gulp.
- `react`, `react-dom` modules are working.
- I tried using another route to my component `./public/js/component/test.jsx` but then I get an error when running my gulp task `Error: Cannot find module './public/js/components/test' from '/Users/myuser/project/public/js'` which means it's finding the correct module like it's right now but not in the browser.
- Tried with and without the `.jsx` extension, same situation.

In case someone wants to look deeper here's the repo:
https://github.com/nramirez/gulp_browserify_es6_babel_react

**What am I missing in order to correctly import my components?**

Comment: Please include the code in the question.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I updated my question with more code details, anyway, I left the links to the complete gist for a wider view.

Comment: Your screenshot does show a console error though. Not related?

Comment: @azium you're right updating!

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the IIFE wrapping `ReactDOM.render` appears to be doing nothing. Were you planning on scoping some variables there later on? Seems odd.

Comment: Yeah, that's the error I was suspecting. I've never loaded modules with browserify and babelify.. have you tried adding the file extension in your import statement? `import TestPage from './components/test.jsx'` ?

Comment: @azium updated! with more details. Yes, IIFE right now is doing nothing but I want to encapsulate my code when I start building the final solution, if I remove it, produces the same behavior.

Comment: @azium I just tried with the extension. Same error!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100937/discussion-between-azium-and-nramirez).

Comment: Are you using Babel6?

Comment: @HenrikAndersson yes, I'm using the last version of babelify (7.2) https://www.npmjs.com/package/babelify

Comment: Then you should read the chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating multiple entry points for your app in your `gulpfile.babel.js` (Basically, you're creating two bundles).

```
const paths = {
  src: './src',
  publicSrc: './public/js',
  dest: './app',
  bundle: 'bundle.js',
  bundleDest: './app/public/js',
  publicEntries: [
    './public/js/index',
    './public/js/components/test' <--- Remove this line.
  ]
};
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks, It's working but I'm really confused now, I'm not supposed to pass all the entries that I pretend to use to browserify?

Comment: No, Browserify traverses all of your `require` calls (Babel transforms the `import ...` to require) and pieces them together when producing the bundle.  Having multiple entry points are only used if you want to have one bundle for url /x and another bundle for /y.

Comment: Nice! Gotcha! Thank you!